# Export DataTable to Excel with C# from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an ASP.NET web forms app with a button on it. This button allows a user to download some content to Excel. However, I'm having problems getting it to work. Everyone has articles that are like export DataGrid or GridView to Excel. My problem is, I have a plain old DataTable. I can't put this DataTable in my UI. At the same time, I do not want to use the Excel libraries.

Does anyone know a way to export a DataTable to Excel with formulas?

Comment: You cannot use Office Interop on an ASP.NET site. It's not designed for that, won't work, and will drive you crazy trying to fix bugs which can't be fixed, except by not using Office Interop on an ASP.NET site.

Comment: How do you have Excel formulas in your DataTable?

Comment: There is a [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/190144/Export-Database-to-Excel-PDF-HTML-RTF-XML-etc-for) about this. You can have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) library (an OpenXML wrapper) to create any Excel you want dynamically.

Comment: I don't think, there is need to use library, its straight forward. Check my answer.

Comment: CSV is not Excel. If you want Excel then OpenXML is the way.

Answer (score 0):

[Office Writer](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-api.aspx) is a very powerful and equally expensive solution which I have used in the past. ClosedXML in Peters answer also looks good (and free).

If you don't need Formulas [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527627/populate-excel-workbook-from-a-view/6529096#6529096) to another SO question may help you out. No library required.